# How to compile a Maven JAR file with JVM args use a plugin?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, javafx-11, openjfx

I'm looking for a Maven plugin that could execute by itself the good JVM arguments.
For now, I've tried using the `maven-compiler-plugin` and the `maven-surefire-plugin` (the pom of my project is down below).

the type of argument I want the jvm to execute is this one:

```
--module-path="C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls
```

in order to launch a javafx app.

the `pom.xml` with the plugin tests.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        //tests with the surefire plugin (without tests).
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                <argLine>--module-path="C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Why would you do that? Have you read the OpenJFX docs to get started with JavaFX 11 and Maven? See https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: yeah but it only works when I run it and not if I launch the java -jar <filePath>.jar like once it-s packaged

Comment: @R.LM that depends on how you've packaged it and are running it as well.

Comment: So how could I package it to run the exec plugin with the java -jar usual launching without any other arguments?

Comment: Keep reading the docs, it is documented